# Combinations for data set with repeated elements

Tags: combinations

For a data set of integers from 1 to 48, $$\binom{48}{4} = 194,580$$ distinct combinations.

And for another data set of 48 integers with 4 subsets of integers from 1 to 12 in each subset, a $$\binom{4\cdot 12}{4} = 194,580$$ as well, but the combinations are NOT distinct because the data set has repeated elements (integers 1 to 12 repeat 4 times).

Here is my question, what general method or formula can be used to count or determine distinct combinations for data set with repeated elements?

Comment: To be clear, you want to allow sets such as $1,1,2,3$ to be chosen, but that would be counted as the same as $1,3,2,1$?

Comment: What combinations are you counting? (Especially in your second example)

Comment: Set (1,1,2,3) is not the same as (1,3,2,1).  Example, set (1,1,2,3) can repeat x times, and set (1,3,2,1) can repeat y times, and I am interested x and y values and/or the number of unique sets from the total 194,580 combinations.

Comment: If your sets (really ordered $4$-tuples) take the form $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ where each $x_i$ is chosen from $\{1,2,\dots,12\}$, then there is only one way in which $(1,1,2,3)$ can be chosen. Similarly, there is only one way $(1,3,2,1)$ can be chosen. Perhaps you want to count the ways that $(1,1,2,3)$ can be rearranged?

Comment: Let me use a smaller data set to explain:  A set of 9 integers consisting of 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 taking 3 items at a time has the  following 84 combinations in 10 distinct groups (the x’s numbers in parentheses representing the number of repetitions -- note that 1x + 9x + 9x + 9x + 27x + 9x + 1x + 9x + 9x + 1x = 84 combinations).

111(1x)
112(9x)
113(9x)
122(9x)
123(27x)
133(9x) 
222(1x)
223(9x)
233(9x)
333(1x)

What method or formula I can use to determine the n groups, and the x repetitions in each group?